# avoiding get limit when request map route on Nokia Here API

Tags: get, maps, limit, routes, here-api

I'm new using this API. I want to request for a route using "Here API". The route xml/json is what I get easyly (I have the Maneuver values with calculateroute method), but I want to show users the map with the route. I have been able to show it using http://image.maps.cit.api.here.com/mia/1.6/route?, but this method only supports GET requests, and many times I have to make requests larger than 2500 characters supported by GET. Is there any other method to get an image with the route from Madrid to Berlin, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you could not use the JS-Maps API as well for showing the route, then you could simply use the waypoints as arguments. You can find example at: https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics/routing.html